# How to get both key/value pairs from Map to TextView

Tags: java, android, json, dictionary

I'm creating an Android app for controlling the configuration of a bartender working with a RPI

I want to show all the current drinks and their ingredients in a listview.

Here is the Json Response I get from the server:

```
    [  
{  
    "name":"Rum & Coke",
    "ingredients":{  
        "rum":50,
        "coke":150
    }
},
{  
    "name":"Gin & Tonic",
    "ingredients":{  
        "tonic":10,
        "gin":10
    }
},
{  
    "name":"Long Island",
    "ingredients":{  
        "tequila":15,
        "oj":30,
        "rum":15,
        "vodka":15,
        "coke":100,
        "gin":15
    }
},
{  
    "name":"Screwdriver",
    "ingredients":{  
        "vodka":50,
        "oj":150
    }
},
{  
    "name":"Margarita",
    "ingredients":{  
        "mmix":150,
        "tequila":50
    }
},
{  
    "name":"Gin & Juice",
    "ingredients":{  
        "oj":150,
        "gin":50
    }
},
{  
    "name":"Tequila Sunrise",
    "ingredients":{  
        "tequila":50,
        "oj":150
    }
}
]
```

And here is the Drink.class

```
public class Drink {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("ingredients")
    private Map<String, Integer> ingredients;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(Map<String, Integer> ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }
}
```

Right now I'm able to show the drinks name inthe listview and only the **second value** of the map with this for statement

```
Drink d = drinksArrayList.get(position);
        System.out.println(d.getIngredients().size());
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> ingredient : d.getIngredients().entrySet()) {
            holder.ingredient0.setText(ingredient.getKey());
            holder.ingredient1.setText(Integer.toString(ingredient.getValue()));
        }
```

This for statement will print the coke 150 to screen in case of the Rum & coke.

Anybody got an idea how I properly serialize this Json and print it to the listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the json is DEserialized properly, but you are using the wrong fields to populate the `TextViews`. You should use `getName` for the name i.e. "Rum & Coke" and then concatenate the map to get the list of ingredients.

I think you want to do something like this:

```
Drink d = drinksArrayList.get(position);
holder.ingredient0.setText(d.getName()));
StringBuilder ingredients = new StringBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> ingredient : d.getIngredients().entrySet()) {
    ingredients.append(" ");
    ingredients.append(ingredient.getKey());
    ingredients.append(", ");
    ingredients.append(Integer.toString(ingredient.getValue()));
    ingredients.append("\n");
}
holder.ingredient1.setText(ingredients.toString().trim());
```